# reCaptcha em aplicação Delphi

Tags: delphi, recaptcha

Estou fazendo uma consulta de CNPJ pelo site da Receita numa aplicação.

Agora eles estão usando o `reCaptcha`, então num *WebBrowser* permito o usuário clicar no **Não sou um Robô** e depois disso, o usuário deve clicar no botão ***Consultar da aplicação***, não dá página exibida no *WebBrowser*.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Tem como eu saber quando o usuário finalizou o processo de validação do `reCaptcha`?

Comparei o código fonte antes e depois da validação, mas não muda nada. Tem alguma maneira? Se houver, como posso saber para daí simular o clique no botão consultar da aplicação ou mesmo ocultar o *WebBrowser*.

Comment: O programa em delphi abre um browser interno com o site da receita?

Comment: Isso mesmo, abro o site da receita apenas para o usuário validar o `reCaptcha`, depois por meio da aplicação leio o `HTML` e preencho os campos no formulário `Delphi`.

Comment: Eu creio que a ideia do reCaptcha é evitar justamente esse tipo de coisa...

Comment: Não estou querendo burlar o `reCaptcha`, afinal o usuário terá que fazer a validação, apenas quero saber quando a validação foi concluída. Será que isso não tem como?

Comment: Olá, tem sim. Não sei se ainda está precisando.
Basta olhar o conteúdo de g-recaptcha-response.
Também é possível realizar o bypass, porém, aqui não é o objetivo. Auxílio NF-e